# Build JAR with custom manifest in maven

Tags: maven, manifest.mf, maven-jar-plugin

I am trying to get maven to create the artifact jar with a custom MANIFEST.MF.

Sounds like an easy task using the following snippet:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestFile>${project.build.directory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Problem is, that the maven-jar-plugin still "messes" with the manifest I created manually. The documentation states

> The content of your own manifest file will be merged with the entries
>   created by Maven Archiver

Unfortunately this is not the case for the Manifest-Version. It will always be set to "1.0". (I know that in theory this is correct, but for reasons I cannot influence, I need a different value in there).
Any ideas on how to step the jar plugin from touching my manifest at all or at least keeping its hands of the Manifest-Version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my problem using the maven-antrun-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <jar file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" update="true" manifest="${project.build.directory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" />
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```